# HTML/CSS div blocks are not placing below each other as written in the document order

Tags: html, css

I'm creating this dummy/template web model for style reference, and the div blocks were working just fine for the first two tags. However, when I try to write the main-container div blocks, it won't be added below my previous div block even though I had all positions in relative.

```css
html {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30pt;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

.banner {
  background-color: #8A100B;
  color: #EDEBDB;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.banner-header {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.banner-image {
  margin: 10px;
}

.banner-content {
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 16pt;
}

.banner-login-button {
  width: 1370px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#button-login {
  text-indent: 0!important;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-image: none!important;
  font-size: 16pt;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #8A100B;
  border: medium none;
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #ede6e6;
  /*border-bottom: 2px solid #CCC;*/
  height: 180px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-header {
  margin-left: 45px;
  color: #404040;
}

.main-container {
  max-width: 1350px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /*margin-top: 231px;*/
}

#menu-container {
  background: #ede6e6;
}

#content-container {
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="banner-image"><img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/778835-200.png" alt="Logo" height="50px" width="70px"></div>
  <div class="banner-header"><strong><p>DummyTemplate</p></strong></div>
  <div class="banner-content">
    <p>Student Registration Waitlist Portal</p>
  </div>
  <div class="banner-login-button">
      <img id="login-icon" src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/778835-200.png" alt="Profile Icon" height="50px" width="50px">
      <button id="button-login" type="button">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <h1>Search Courses/My Requests</h1>
    <!--try to get it to work with site name-->
  </div>

  <main class="main-container">
    <section id="menu-container">
      <p>placeholder</p>
    </section>

    <section id="content-container">
      <p>placeholder</p>
    </section>
  </main>
```

**What it looks like now**
[image]

**What I'm trying to achieve**
[image]

Comment: If you could fix the image links in the code snippet or just remove them if they aren't important that would be great

Comment: Terry, could you describe more? that, what you want to achieve and how you think to implement this thing. it is not entirely clear in your question.

Comment: @Zachiah Got it! I'll do that now

Comment: @DSDmark My apologies, I was trying to create this main body that contains two columns (menu<->mainBody) below the navbar, however when I added the main section placeholders, it automatically added next to the nav-header line.

Comment: you're trying to create a web layout with HTML and CSS. if I'm not wrong

Comment: @DSDmark Yes indeed :)

Comment: Have you tried this:

`.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#menu-container {
  flex: 1; 
}

#content-container {
  flex: 2; /* Adjust the ratio as needed */
}`

Comment: Kindly include { flex-direction: column } 
The default for flex-direction is row.

That wil keep the main.main-container down

Comment: @DSDmark thank you! I just tried, it's still not working... Let me probably rewrite everything and see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly include { flex-direction: column }
The default for flex-direction is row.

Comment: Before posting this, I tried to set the entire html and body tag as flex display and column direction, it didn't work